# Maven project with Mybatis-Generator-Maven-Plugin, nested module dependency problem

Tags: java, maven, mybatis, mybatis-generator

The whole project dependencies are looking like this:

```
- parent
  - child-a
    - pom.xml
  - child-b
    - src.main.java.resources
      - mybatis-generator.xml
    - pom.xml
  - pom.xml
```

**parent, pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>child-a</module>
    <module>child-b</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**child-b, pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>child-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- other configs -->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When packaging child-b project/module solely，all dependencies were handled properly(child-a was imported as expected).

**Problem:**

When I'm trying to run `mvn mybatis-generator:generate` in the directory of `child-b`:

`Error: Failed to execute goal on project service_a: Could not resolve dependencies for project xx.xx.child-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact xx.xx.child-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

When you run maven from a nested project, it will only succeed if all the dependencies are available in your local repo. I can reproduce this if I delete a dependency from my local repo and try it on one of my projects.

Snapshot dependencies add another level of complexity in that they expire - meaning maven will look for a newer version if the version in your local repo is not considered current. They may be why a package ran at some point, but later on another maven commend like running the generator failed.

Bottom line...when snapshot dependencies are involved with nested projects, the only reliable way to run maven is to run the entire project (run maven from the parent directory).